# Is there any way to restore click-to-play for Flash in Google Chrome 55 and above

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome 55 removed 'click to play' for plugins and the user has only the option to allow, block, or leave Chrome detect and decide when to run Flash.

None of these is a good as the old click-to-play functionality, which enabled fine-grained control allowing only specific plugin instances on one page.

Is there a way (via a plugin, flags, etc) to restore the previous click-to-play behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand: although Google removed the click-to-play config option, you can still achieve the same fine-grained control on every individual Flash widget on a page. Just do the three steps below and the following statement will replace **each** Flash video: `Right-click to run Adobe Flash Player`

1. on the address bar, type `chrome://settings/content`
2. scroll down to the 'Flash' section (default='Detect and run....')
3. select 'Block sites from running Flash', then click 'Done'